# How to set the value of inputs with ReactJS hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to fill the inputs value of a form with default values once the modal is opened

I did it with pure javascript using `document.getElementById(textId).value='some value` as follow:

```
  for(var i=0; i<details_data.length;i++){
     let textId='text'+i;
     let amountId='amount'+i;
     document.getElementById(textId).value=details_data[i].text
  }
```

This worked fine. but I want to know how to do it with React since I don't believe this is a best practice.

what i tried is to set the input value like this:

```
<input name='text' id={textId} value={el.text} onChange={details_handler.bind(index)}/>
```

But this woudn't let me change the value of the input. it just set the default value, and when i type in the input the value woudn't change as I want.

**This is my code**

```
const [details_data,set_details_data]=useState([
    {'text':'','amount':''}
])
// called this function on `onChange` and store the data in `details_data`
function details_handler(e){
    let name=e.target.name;
    let value=e.target.value;
    details_data[this][name]=value;
    set_details_data(details_data);
  }
```

**JSX:**

(In my case user can add inputs as many as he wants,That's why I put the inputs in a the mapping loop)

```
  {
    details_data.map((el,index) => {
        let textId='text'+index;
        let amountId='amount'+index;
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <input name='text' id={textId} value={el.text} onChange={details_handler.bind(index)}/>
                <input name='amount' id={amountId} onChange={details_handler.bind(index)}/>
            </div>
            );
      })
  }
```

Comment: What are the props you are receiving to your modal? And does does have multiple text and amount.

Comment: @karrthik There are no props, the values are coming from an API request. And yes, user might add new inputs. But suppose i only have these inputs since it doesn't matter the number of inputs, if you can help out with these example i can apply the concept on different scenarios.

Comment: Posted an answer. Please check it.

Comment: let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Karrthik The values are correctly set but can't be changed. when i type in the input nothing happened but keep the values that are coming from the response

Comment: updating the answer how your input and on change should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 useEffect(() => {
     if(detailsProps) {
         set_details_data(detailsProps);
     }
 }, [detailsProps])
```

where your detailsProps (data from the api) will look something like this

```
 detailsProps = [
    {'text':'text1','amount':'100'},
    {'text':'text2','amount':'200'}
 ]
```

onChange Function

```
const details_handler = (event, index) => {
   const items = [...details_data];
   items[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
   set_details_data(items);
}
```

your view

```
 {
details_data.map((el,index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <input name='text' value={el.text} onChange={(e) => details_handler(e, index)}/>
            <input name='amount' value={el.amount} onChange={(e) => details_handler(e, index)}/>
        </div>
        );
  })
}
```

Comment: just need to change `event` to `e` in the handler function to be same as the params

Comment: Thanks. Updating the answer.  Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: I dont know the complete code of your file but I assumed your modal was in some other file and you wanted to pass it as props. In react props will be passed to component multiple times you shouldn't update the component state multiple times. here [detailsProps] is acting as subscribed and if there is change in detailsProps it executes the internal code. if it is in same file you can directly update the state after api call only once.

Answer (score 0):

Its so difficult to understand why so many offer bad advice when it comes to setting the value of a React input.  All of this business with implementing onChange events because when you set the value of the text input you can't edit it is so very easy to overcome and you don't need hooks for that.  Using the onChange event bandaid, simply generates tons of events that simply are not needed.

Consider the following Custom control:

```
export default function TextInput({name, initialValue}:
    {name:string, initialValue?:string}) {
    return(<input type="text" name={name} defaultValue={initialValue}/>)
}
```

Right off the bat, when this control renders the initial value becomes the control value and then the control can be edited like any other web form input.

If you want the control to respond to hooks then in the parent form you can use State as follows:

```
export default function ParentForm() {
    const values = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState(values[index]);

    const modTheValue = (event: any) =>{
       if(index < 2)
           setIndex(index+1);
       else
           setIndex(0);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       setSomeValue(values[index])
    },[index])


    return(
        <form>
            <TextInput name="someInput" initialValue={someValue}/>
            <button type="button" onclick={modTheValue}>Change It</button>
        </form>
    )

}
```

Here when you click Change it, the index state variable gets updated.  Then sometime later useEffect detects a change in index, and then calls setSomeValue with a new value, this causes the TextInput to re-render and gets the current someValue as the initial value.